# Error creating Controller in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to create a controller using scaffolding

[image]

I have my EF Core context and my domain classes

But I get this error

[image]

Error executing the selected code generator...

Any idea, please?

Thanks

Comment: Please rebuild the whole application and try again

Comment: @BrandoZhang I have already tried that several times by previously cleaning the solution but I still have the same problem

Comment: If you build your application does it contain this error?

Comment: No. All goes fine